# how to have such a background flash animation on mousehover using jquery

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-animate

You can see 2 kinds of animation [here](http://www.geneticlimited.com/body.php) :

1) the text 'GENETIC LIMITED' on the top left has an animation

2) the left side vertical menu (home, payment & policy etc) has a color animation on mouse hover.

Flash is used in both cases.How can I achieve the same effect with jquery?
I saw the jquery color plugins and other things  ( [here](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) , [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/#demo) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)  ) but that does not seem to be any solution to my problem.

Any solution please?

Comment: for having effect of generic limited text, you should use a js or jquery plugin, the second one is not based on flash, you can create the same effect easily by using jquery [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method.

Comment: any code snippet in the form of an answer please?