# jquery mobile data trasfer between section

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm doing mobile website based on JQM and http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49735179/dialog-data-transfer.html .

If click submit button from  one of search result on section "dialogPage", 
It supposed to be shown on section "mainPage" of zip1, zip2, addr  form.

But the form value of zip_code1, zip_code2, addr 
are not tranfered to section "mainPage".

What is the problem in this script?

Here is full script + html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<title>Test Dialog</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(){
var inputVal1 = $('input[name=zip_code1]').val();
var inputVal2 = $('input[name=zip_code1]').val();
var inputVal3 = $('input[name=addr]').val();
$("#mainPage").data("inputVal1", inputVal1);
$("#mainPage").data("inputVal2", inputVal2);
$("#mainPage").data("inputVal3", inputVal3);

})
});
$('#mainPage').live('pageshow', function(){
var inputVal1 = $(this).data('inputVal1') ? $(this).data('inputVal1') : "<? $defaultValue1 ?>";
var inputVal2 = $(this).data('inputVal2') ? $(this).data('inputVal2') : "<? $defaultValue2 ?>";
var inputVal3 = $(this).data('inputVal3') ? $(this).data('inputVal3') : "<? $defaultValue3 ?>";

$('div input[name=zip1]').val(inputVal1);
$('div input[name=zip2]').val(inputVal2);
$('div input[name=addr]').val(inputVal3);
});

</script>




<section id="mainPage" data-role="page">
<header data-role="header"><h1>Header</h1></header>
<div data-role="content">
<div>
<input type="text" name="zip1" value="">-<input type="text" name="zip2" value="">
<input type="text" name="addr" value="">
</div>

<a href="#dialogPage" data-role="button" data-transition="pop">Open Dialog</a>
</div>
<footer data-role="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></footer>
   </section>

   <!-- ## DIALOGS ## -->
   <section id="dialogPage" data-role="dialog" data-theme="d">
<header data-role="header"><h1>Header</h1></header>
<div data-role="content">
<h3>Input Dialog</h3>

<INPUT type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" id="k"><input type="submit" value="search" onClick="kin()" data-role="button">           
<DIV id="serverMsg"></DIV>      

           <form>
            <input type=hidden name=zip_code1 value='code1'>
            <input type=hidden name=zip_code2 value='code2'>
            <input type=hidden name=addr value='address1'>
            <table><tr>
            <td width=50>code1 - code2</td>
            <td>address1</td>
          </tr></table>
          <input type="submit" value='address1' /> 
          </form>

           <form>
            <input type=hidden name=zip_code1 value='code4'>
            <input type=hidden name=zip_code2 value='code5'>
            <input type=hidden name=addr value='address2'>
            <table><tr>
            <td width=50>code4 - code5</td>
            <td>address2</td>
          </tr></table>
          <input type="submit" value='address2' /> 
          </form>

           <form>
            <input type=hidden name=zip_code1 value='code6'>
            <input type=hidden name=zip_code2 value='code7'>
            <input type=hidden name=addr value='address2'>
            <table><tr>
            <td width=50>code6 - code7</td>
            <td>address3</td>
          </tr></table>
          <input type="submit" value='address3' /> 
          </form>              

    </div>

</div>
<footer data-role="footer"></footer>
  </section>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `attr` method, `data()` method does not create a `data` attribute;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(){
var inputVal1 = $('input[name=zip_code1]').val();
var inputVal2 = $('input[name=zip_code1]').val();
var inputVal3 = $('input[name=addr]').val();
$("#mainPage").attr("data-inputVal1", inputVal1);
$("#mainPage").attr("data-inputVal2", inputVal2);
$("#mainPage").attr("data-inputVal3", inputVal3);
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed to 
$("#mainPage").attr("data-inputVal1", inputVal1);    $("#mainPage").attr("data-inputVal2", inputVal2); $("#mainPage").attr("data-inputVal3", inputVal3);  

But still i didn't return valuse from section "dialogPage".  
I think there is some problems on "dialogPage".

Comment: @undefined, may I request to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969074/how-to-have-such-a-background-flash-animation-on-mousehover-using-jquery? A jquery question on a different topic. I do not know whether such comments are permissible in SE?

Comment: @paulycho you are welcome, you have 3 form elements on one page, try it with one form.

Comment: If i made only one form, then it work fine. But the problem is the search result of "dialogPage" is multiple(there should be a lot of forms). How can i indentified each result as unique value when it get back to "mainPage"?